# Is it possible to auto-start a WCF for only specific projects?

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

I have a WCF project which several other projects depend on, but others, like unit testing projects and other support utilities which don't need the service.  It contains the following XML in the .csproj file:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
  <VisualStudio>
    <FlavorProperties GUID="{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}">
      <WcfProjectProperties>
        <AutoStart>True</AutoStart>
      </WcfProjectProperties>
    </FlavorProperties>
  </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

Is there a way to get the "auto-start service with project" functionality to only apply to specific projects in the solution?  Or is it all or nothing?  Is there anything I could add to the other projects to tell them they depend on this service to make it auto-start in the debugging session?  Or add some condition to the service's .csproj that depends on which project is the current startup project?

I tried experimenting with Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" in various places, but I couldn't get it to behave an different based on that Configuration variable.

Comment: This isn't a question about unit testing.  This is about having multiple projects in the same solution, and some depend on the service and others don't, so I don't want to start the service for ones that don't.  A unit test project is simply an example of a project which doesn't depend on the service.

Comment: Thank-you for the clarification

Comment: How do other projects rely on WCF services? Is the relationship between the client-side and the server-side?

Comment: @DingPeng I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  One solution contains: 1 service, 3 client applications which connect to that service, and 5 other executables which stand on their own.  The client applications connect to localhost during development, and the service starts when any of the projects are launched.  You can then step into calls on the client side, and it will step into the code on the service side.

Comment: If the dependency is the relationship between the client-side and the server-side, you can deploy the WCF service to IIS.

Comment: I'm not interested in deploying the service during development.  I want to debug the service on my local machine together with the client application (which is a supported scenario).  I'm just trying to figure out how to turn it off for applications that don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the client applications debugable, create a new tiny project and set both the service and the client application as dependencies.  The only file it should contain is Program.cs, and its only function should look like this:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(MyServiceClass)).Open();
    MyClientApplication.Program.Main(args);
}
```

And then merge the app.config for both into a single app.config for this tiny application.  But now the service is hosted inside the same process as the client, and they can both be debugged interchangeably.

This allows removing the AutoStart feature from the service, but still run the client application together with the service.